# Turning toasted, non-crumbly whole wheat bread into breadcrumbs

Tags: bread, breadcrumbs

I've got some toasted 100% whole wheat homemade bread that I would like to turn into breadcrumbs. How can I do that? It doesn't crumble easily.

Answer (score 4):

A coffee grinder or food processor both work well. Drying the bread at low oven temperature will aid the crumbling.